# How to use index function on string with hyphen?

Tags: python, anaconda

I am developing a script to parse through a ton of resumes, and the index function doesn't seem to recognize headers that use hyphens.

```
doc = docx.Document("OMALLEY_KIMBERLY.docx");
statements = [para.text.strip() for para in doc.paragraphs
             if para.text.strip() != '']

statements.index("Peer-Reviewed Journal Articles")
```

Below is the traceback.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-89-a1e9c115d1c9> in <module>()
     11              if para.text.strip() != '']
     12 
---> 13 statements.index("Peer-Reviewed Journal Articles")

ValueError: 'Peer-Reviewed Journal Articles' is not in list
```

I've tried `statements.index("Peer\-Reviewed Journal Articles")` with the same results.

Comment: `'Peer-Reviewed Journal Articles' is not in list` apparently has nothing to do with hyphens, it's just a wrong argument type: a list is expected, when you pass a string.

Comment: If you think that was the wrong result, then prove it. print statements[x] where x is the correct result.